# A more formal word for "tech-savvy", relating to IT technologists in particular

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Good morning. I'm struggling with formalizing this sentence:

> Online password managers are popular among *tech-savvies*.

This is too casual--I would like a better word for *tech-savvies*, preferably describing someone knowledgeable about IT/computers, i.e. a *power user* of sorts.

Comment: What's wrong with "power users"?

Comment: @Andrew Leach. Ambiguity? I have the light on at the moment. Doesn't that make me a power user?

Comment: @BarrieEngland As with so many questions here, context is everything.

Comment: @AndrewLeach *power user* may sound alright for a power user. However, for humans, as Barrie England points out, it's not distinctive enough, or even sufficiently established (IMO it feels rather "slang-y").

Comment: I would definitely prefer *'the pros'* any day. Tells me what is meant quickly without a fuss.

Comment: I would say the bike shed should be green. It'll blend in with the trees.

Comment: The problem with the noun "tech-savvies" isn't the "tech-savvy" part, it's the *noun* part.

Comment: technically-skilled people. i did not see this word here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use technophile:

Online password managers are popular among ***technophiles***.

> From Dictionary.reference.com:
>
> 1. a person who loves or is enthusiastic about advanced technology.

Comment: This may or may not be suitable for the OP, as a technophile is simply a technology enthusiast— and an enthusiast, in any field, need merely be enthusiastic, not necessarily knowledgeable or competent.

Comment: @choster, I agree with you. I think technophile is suitable, with some wiggle room for a more appropriate word.  The OP's first word, tech-savvies, has some ambiguity too since you can be "savvy" on a topic but not necessarily be a power user.

Comment: Tech-loving is not necessarily tech-knowing, and vice versa. The OP should have picked one of the answers that reflects the same meaning (e.g. "technically proficient").

Comment: disagree with this. It implies being tech savvy means you love technology and if you're not tech savvy you hate it.... my grandad loved technology though he wasn't particularly tech savvy.

Answer (score 8):

> Online password managers are popular among the more technically proficient.

Answer (score 6):

Two portmanteau neologisms that might fit the bill are:

> **Technocrat**
>
> An elite within a technical group.
>
> **Digerati**
>
> An elite group with an online community.

It's debatable whether either are real words yet, but I've seen both used a great deal in the UK press.

Comment: Both have entries in the Oxford English Dictionary, but they may not be appropriate in the context the OP has given us.

Answer (score 6):

Before "tech-savvy", I always used to use "computer literate".

Answer (score 5):

> Online password managers are popular among ***_*____**.

I can't really think of a single word *formal* answer. IMO, *IT professionals* are implicitly considered *power users*. *Computer experts* might fall in the same category. I would also consider *techies* or for added emphasis *seasoned techies*. While it is a tad informal, I've seen *techies* used [just](http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/#/techie) about [everywhere](http://www.google.com/search?q=techie&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks).

As online password managers are not used *only* by IT professionals, you could also simply state *experienced/seasoned internet users*.

Comment: +1 for "techies". While informal, it's pretty universal, plus I'm not sure if using "tech savvy" as a noun as the OP does is at all common.

Answer (score 2):

*The technically literate* and *those familiar with technology* are possible alternatives, but there may well be more.

Comment: Though _"technologically literate"_ might be a better choice of words than _"technically literate"_.

Comment: @IQAndreas. I agree.

Answer (score 1):

You could be a bit more explicit about the context. So instead of worrying about finding an appropriate word for techies in general, the sentence may be better if you convey *why* some people prefer password managers. e.g. "Online password managers are popular among security-conscious users". That way you educate readers a little about what password managers are for.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use *cognoscenti*, as in

> Online password managers are popular among the cognoscenti.

This is the plural of [*cognoscente*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cognoscenti), which means

> A person with superior, usually specialized knowledge or highly refined taste; a connoisseur.

Answer (score 0):

> Online password managers are popular among **_**.

Possible answers are:

- tech-geeks
- tech-nerds
- code-breakers
- tech-super-users
- software-techies
- blue-collared-workforce
- IT-workforce
- IT-taskforce
- IT-metausers

Answer (score 0):

I know this would add a bit more, but you could say something like, "system administrators." That would imply these people "do computers" for a living, but you could soften that by stating they are popular among "system administrators and computer enthusiasts alike."

Also, since you are making a claim, you may need a source (if this is a formal paper (just a thought)).