# What do you call someone who is able to learn the new technologies?

Tags: single-word-requests

As I renovate my [CV](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/cv/), I would like to find a word (or two) to replace this phrase:

```
Able to learn state of art technologies
```

So for example one would say:

> George is able to learn state-of-the-art technologies, because he
>   knows the concepts well.

Now the questions asks for `X`, so that we could say:

> George is `X`, because he knows the concepts well.

Comment: Related: [A more formal word for “tech-savvy”, relating to IT technologists in particular](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94561/a-more-formal-word-for-tech-savvy-relating-to-it-technologists-in-particular)

Comment: It sounds as if you are trying to communicate that you have a **proven ability to learn new technologies**. Is there a good reason that it needs to be a shorter phrase than that?

Comment: @pyobum I don't agree. The answer there says **technophiles**, which at least to a *Greek* like me sounds like friends of techno(logy), which is not what am I looking for, is it? nekomatic, my girlfriend said I should minify my CV. :P

Comment: Why not just call yourself a *quick learner*?

Comment: I am not sure if that's the same @Darthfett, since it might be referring to learning anything quickly, for example bubblesort..I guess.

Comment: @gsamaras I agree; I don't think technophile is a good fit either. I just wanted to link the question because it seemed related to yours.

Comment: @gsamaras Please see the comments section below my answer. It is possible that a better word exists in lieu of **adaptable**. If you like the comment better then I can update my answer to reflect it or provide a new answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> George is highly enthusiastic and **adaptable** with the latest technologies and advancements.

[**Adaptable:**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adaptable) able to change or be changed in order to fit or work better in some situation or for some purpose : able to adapt or be adapted.

Comment: *Adaptable* usually connotes someone who can “roll with the punches” rather than someone who can learn new technologies.

Comment: @Jim Would "George is highly enthusiastic and adept in the latest technologies and advancements." be more correct?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus- Yes, that sounds much better.

Comment: @Jim Thanks, I'll see what the OP wants and possibly post a new answer or update this one.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus your call, I trust you.

Answer (score 8):

It may not be the most precise answer as it relates more closely to an understanding of existing technologies, but [*tech-savvy*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tech-savvy) makes some implication that a person would be capable of learning new technologies as well, and it's perhaps the most apt single-word choice.

> George is *tech-savvy*, because he knows the concepts well.

Comment: *Tech-savvy* isn't really appropriate for a CV.

Comment: As mentioned in the related question I linked to above, a more formal choice could be "technologically literate" (or "technologically proficient/adept"), but the OP requested a single word...

Comment: @pyobum but the OP requested on word (or two), thanks! :)

Comment: @gsamaras Indeed, I read back through and noticed that after dashing off that comment. :( So maybe"technologically literate" would work after all.

Answer (score 6):

You could consider using [*early adopter*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/early-adopter) if you want to emphasize the fact that George is able and eager to learn new technologies before they become widely available. Early adopters are usually tech-savvy.

> a person who uses a new product or technology before it becomes widely
>   known or used.

[Dictionary.com]

> An individual or business who uses a new product or technology before
>   others. An early adopter is likely to pay more for the product than
>   later adopters, but accepts this premium if using the product improves
>   efficiency, reduces cost, increases market penetration or simply
>   raises the early adopter's social status.

[[Investopedia.com](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/early-adopter.asp)]

Answer (score 3):

The best example can be the word **to be inclined**.

[Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incline?q=inclined) has the possible answers for it.

*inclined - have a specified disposition or talent*

**George is inclined to learn state-of-art technologies, because he knows concepts well**

**George is technologically inclined, so he can learn state-of-art technologies easily.**

Comment: *Inclined* is a bit weak for a CV.

Answer (score 3):

A **quick study**.

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quick%20study),
*one that can speedily learn the essentials of something to be done; especially :  a performer (as an actor, musician) with a gift for learning with remarkable speed new material (as lines, stage business, scores)*

Comment: That will be an alternative!

Answer (score 2):

> George is highly enthusiastic and **adept** in the latest technologies and advancements.

[**Adept:**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adept) a highly skilled or well-trained person : someone who is adept at something

Answer (score -1):

> [**Digerati**](https://books.google.com/books?id=MMlMAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=%22people+with+expertise+or+professional+involvement+in+information+technology.%22&source=bl&ots=mMtRjzeflZ&sig=6k4du6MipJugdjsAUrA7NNP2GCA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiz3siP6ZLOAhVnyoMKHUsPD94Q6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=%22people%20with%20expertise%20or%20professional%20involvement%20in%20information%20technology.%22&f=false) dijəˈrätē
>   Plural n.
>   people with expertise or professional involvement in information technology.
>
> ---
>
> *1001 Computer Words You Need to Know* Author: Jerry Pournelle; Publisher: Oxford University Press.