# Words for Technology enthusiastic

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to fill in the space in the following sentence a proper word that means **Technology enthusiastic**

> With an inquisitive and ___ personality, I am confident ...

I've tried couple synonyms from [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94561/a-more-formal-word-for-tech-savvy-relating-to-it-technologists-in-particular) but all seem out of place.

Comment: I think the problem is that a personality is not generally considered to be tech savvy. You may be, but your personality isn’t.

Comment: What's wrong with technophilic?

Comment: +1 for the research.

Comment: The linked question offers only nouns, which aren't always easy to make into adjectives. However, it would be useful to say what the adjectives you form are, and why they "seem out of place". [Help for this sort of question](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Comment: @HotLicks I also like **technophilic** (+1). It's more accurate and inclusive than **tech-savvy** because the latter term implies knowledge and skill whereas the former only implies enthusiasm. It's a bit like the difference between being a music lover and a musician.

Answer (score 1):

A person who is enthusiastic about technology, an 'early adopter', is often referred to as a:

> technophile.

The adjective form of this is

> technophilic,

but that is much less common and might sound a little strange.

You could use the much easier to understand

> technology-loving.